# mquery - how to replace if-clause with merge/join

Tags: if-statement, merge, powerquery

I have a the following code in multiple powerqueries:

```
    #"Currency" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "curreny", 
        each if [Type] = 1 then 
            "EUR" 
        else if [Type] = 2 then
            "USD"
        else if [Type] = 3 then
            "GBP"
        else 
            "other")
```

My problem is that I sometimes have to extend this if-clause if a new value occurs in the data that has to been shown separate. E.g.:

```
        else if [Type] = 4 then
            "NOK"
```

Therefore I was thinking to create a mapping table where I can easy add a new value and merge this table with my data.

| Type | Currency |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | EUR |
| 2 | USD |
| 3 | GBP |
| else | Other |

But how can I handle the else when using a mapping table?

Regards,
Andreas

Answer (score 0):

After you merge (left outer) and expand the column using the arrow arop the new column, replace the null with a value such as

```
 x = Table.ReplaceValue(#"PriorStepNameHere",null,"aaa", Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"ColumnNameHere"})
```